# math.random() numbers not reseeding Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to get random numbers every time a function is called using Math.random(). For whatever reason the same two numbers are picked for every call (only random for the first call)

The RockpaperScissorsLizardSpock() object has a method for calling random numbers, but I bypassed it for testing by just having the play method take random numbers directly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    RockPaperScissorsLizardSpock game = new RockPaperScissorsLizardSpock();
    while(game.getConsecutiveWins()<4){
        game.play(((int)(Math.random()*5)+1),((int)(Math.random()*5)+1));
    }
    if (game.getLastWinner()==1){
        System.out.println(System.lineSeparator() + "Player 1 Wins!");
    } else{
        System.out.println(System.lineSeparator() + "Player 2 Wins!");
    }

}
```

The while loop should run until four games are won consecutively(which it does).

> Player 1 Chooses Rock
>   Player 2 chooses Spock.
>   Spock. beats Rock. Player 2 wins
>
> Player 1 Chooses Rock
>   Player 2 chooses Spock.
>   Spock. beats Rock. Player 2 wins
>
> Player 1 Chooses Rock
>   Player 2 chooses Spock.
>   Spock. beats Rock. Player 2 wins
>
> Player 1 Chooses Rock
>   Player 2 chooses Spock.
>   Spock. beats Rock. Player 2 wins
>
> Player 2 Wins!

Here is the game method being called in case it is relevant:

```
public void play(int player1, int player2){
    consecutiveWins = 0;
    lastWinner = 0;

    while (consecutiveWins<4){
    int p1Choice = player1;
    int p2Choice = player2;
    int pWinner = 0;

    switch (p1Choice) {
        case 1://Player 1 rock              

            System.out.println("Player 1 Chooses Rock");
            if (p2Choice == 1){ //Player 1 rock vs Player 2 rock - tie
                pWinner = 0;
            } else if (p2Choice == 2){ 
                pWinner = 2;//P2 paper - P2
            } else if (p2Choice == 3){// P2 Scissors - P1 Wins                    
                pWinner = 1;
            } else if (p2Choice == 4){//P2 Lizard - P1 Win
                pWinner = 1;
            }else {//p2 spock = P2 Win
                pWinner = 2;
            }
            break;

        case 2: //P1 paper -- not done

            System.out.println("Player 1 Chooses Paper");
            if (p2Choice == 1){ //Player 1 rock vs Player 2 rock - tie
                pWinner = 0;
            } else if (p2Choice == 2){ 
                pWinner = 2;//P2 paper - P2
            } else if (p2Choice == 3){// P2 Scissors - P1 Wins                    
                pWinner = 1;
            } else if (p2Choice == 4){//P2 Lizard - P1 Win
                pWinner = 1;
            }else {//p2 spock = P2 Win
                pWinner = 2;
            }
            break; 

            case 3: //P1 scissors -- not done

            System.out.println("Player 1 Chooses Scissors");
            if (p2Choice == 1){ //Player 1 rock vs Player 2 rock - tie
                pWinner = 0;
            } else if (p2Choice == 2){ 
                pWinner = 2;//P2 paper - P2
            } else if (p2Choice == 3){// P2 Scissors - P1 Wins                    
                pWinner = 1;
            } else if (p2Choice == 4){//P2 Lizard - P1 Win
                pWinner = 1;
            }else {//p2 spock = P2 Win
                pWinner = 2;
            }
            break; 

            case 4: //P1 lizard -- not done

            System.out.println("Player 1 Chooses Lizard");
            if (p2Choice == 1){ //Player 1 rock vs Player 2 rock - tie
                pWinner = 0;
            } else if (p2Choice == 2){ 
                pWinner = 2;//P2 paper - P2
            } else if (p2Choice == 3){// P2 Scissors - P1 Wins                    
                pWinner = 1;
            } else if (p2Choice == 4){//P2 Lizard - P1 Win
                pWinner = 1;
            }else {//p2 spock = P2 Win
                pWinner = 2;
            }
            break; 

            case 5: //P1 Spock -- not done

            System.out.println("Player 1 Chooses Spock");                    
            if (p2Choice == 1){ //Player 1 rock vs Player 2 rock - tie
                pWinner = 0;
            } else if (p2Choice == 2){ 
                pWinner = 2;//P2 paper - P2
            } else if (p2Choice == 3){// P2 Scissors - P1 Wins                    
                pWinner = 1;
            } else if (p2Choice == 4){//P2 Lizard - P1 Win
                pWinner = 1;
            }else {//p2 spock = P2 Win
                pWinner = 2;
            }
            break;
    }

    if(pWinner==1){
        System.out.println("Player 2 chooses " + convert(p2Choice));
        System.out.println(convert(p1Choice) + " beats " + 
            convert(p2Choice) + " Player 1 wins" + System.lineSeparator());
        if(lastWinner == PLAYER1){
            consecutiveWins +=1;
        }else{
            lastWinner = PLAYER1;
            consecutiveWins = 1;
        }
    } else if (pWinner==2){
        System.out.println("Player 2 chooses " + convert(p2Choice));
        System.out.println(convert(p2Choice) + " beats " + 
            convert(p1Choice) + " Player 2 wins" + System.lineSeparator());

        if(lastWinner == PLAYER2){
            consecutiveWins +=1;
        }else{
            lastWinner = PLAYER2;
            consecutiveWins = 1;
        }               
    } else {
        System.out.println("Player 2 also chooses " + convert(p2Choice));
        System.out.println("It's a tie!");
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: May be something wrong in `game.play` method?

Comment: You have to share the code behind game.play. Otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a value from `0.0` to `1.0`. That multiplication by 5 looks shady to me

Comment: Whats the code for your RockPaperScissorsLizardSpock Class? i cant see an issue from what you posted so far. Also @ mnetorov check this [out](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-math-random-method-examples/) this shows how the t multiplication by 5 works.

Comment: added the game method to the post.

Comment: @mnestorov `[0.0, 1.0) * 5  =  [0.0, 5.0);  [0.0, 5.0) + 1 = [1.0, 6.0); (int) (1.0, 6.0] = (1, 6] = (1, 5)` It's fine.

Comment: Note that I see a lot of repeated code. Try to rethink your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop in the play method is superfluous and should be removed.

```
while (consecutiveWins<4){
```

EDIT: to prevent an infinite loop, you must also move

```
consecutiveWins = 0;
```

out of the play method (possibly into the constructor)

Comment: then whats the point of the one in the main method?

Comment: The method play returns after it gets the 4 consecutive and because of this it will use the same ints every time as it break the condition in the main.

Comment: @Micheal: Note that there are 2 loops. The random is done in the outer loop (in the main method), the inner loop (in the play method) is superfluous .

Comment: @Michael your stubbed implementation leaves out the superfluous loop in the `play` method. That's the loop my answer is about.

Comment: oh.. it was edited in after i read it... sorry about that

Comment: OP did not paste the whole output, his question is misleading.

Comment: @Murat Karagöz -- that was the whole output.